# Почему плагин Autoptimize не работает вообще на сайте Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Друзья, весь день ломаю голову, плагин Autoptimize не минифицирует вообще, не могу понять с чем это связанно, буду благодарна за любую помощь